# Set new object location on button click?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out change an object's location on the screen when someone clicks a button. For example image 1 should move to  {'x' : '300' , 'y' : '200'}, when a button is clicked.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: First suggestion: share your code and what you have tried so far!

Comment: Is jQuery allowed, or do you want pure JavaScript solution?

Comment: I'm unsure how to start. Either is great Dmitriy!

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi I've posted both. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you have the following in your HTML layout:

```
<button id="button1">Click</button>
<img src="..." id="image1" />
```

you can do something like this in a script file (pure JavaScript):

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");

button1.click = function()
{
    image1.style.position = "absolute";
    image1.style.top = "300px";
    image1.style.left = "200px";
};
```

or with jQuery/Zepto.js:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#button1").on("click", function()
    {
        $("#image1").css({position: "absolute", top: "300px", left: "200px"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn").on ("click", function() {
    $(".image1").css({top: 300px, left: 200px});
});
```

this should do the trick